# NetBeans IDE for PHP/Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, svn, ide, netbeans

I just came across NetBeans site and found its PHP and Ruby IDEs. I want to know how popular is NetBeans and are the plugins for SVN really as good as the plugins for Eclipse?

Comment: You think the Eclipse svn plugin is *good*? :-)

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Yeah. I am using Subversive plugin with Aptana and it works great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use NetBeans at work for Java and UML and at home for C, C++, Java, UML, and Python. I have no problems with it or it's support for version control systems, such as SVN, CVS, and ClearCase. It's just as easy, if not easier, than Eclipse to get everything working the way you want to. However, I have found that for some things, it might be more difficult to find a plugin for.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans has very good SVN integration out of the box — no plugins required.  Choosing between it and Eclipse is largely a matter of taste, as they are both very well built and supported.

Answer (score 1):

I have using the Ruby Netbeans IDE for almost a year now. For PHP I still stick to Eclipse.

As far as Ruby is concerned its one best IDEs around and SVN is as easy as it is in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use Eclipse for PHP development. I haven't used NetBeans for it yet, but what's keeping you from switching everything to NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Netbeans for PHP since about 8 months ago and I love it (I used to use Eclipse and prior to that Zend Studio). My workflow requires heavy use of SVN as well as some use of the built-in FTP functionality and I have no complaints. Solid, free IDE.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you [netbeans](http://netbeans.com) .its free. it is available for all platforms, and mostly it is good for editing php, jsp, java, css, html, ...
Good for SVN, mercurial, Plus you can integrate it easyly with [kenai.com](http://kenai.com)...

believe me, i'm using it for php development and its the best suited ide i can find...